# NSData issue on iPhone5 and iPod touch (5th gen) through GKMatch

Tags: nsdata, messaging, game-center

I have a typedef struct

```
typedef struct {
    Message message;
    uint32_t randomNumber;
} MessageRandomNumber;
```

I have this code to send a random number to all other players in a GKMatch:

```
-(void)sendRandomNumber {

MessageRandomNumber message;
message.message.messageType = kMessageTypeRandomNumber;
message.randomNumber = _ourRandomNumber;
NSLog(@"My random number is %d", _ourRandomNumber);
NSData * data = [NSData dataWithBytes:&message length:sizeof(MessageRandomNumber)];
NSLog(@"Sent my random number to the other players");
[MultiplayerNetworking sendData:data];
}

+(void)sendData:(NSData *)data {

NSError * error;

GCTurnBasedMatchHelper * gamekitHelper = [GCTurnBasedMatchHelper sharedGameKitHelper];

BOOL success = [gamekitHelper.match sendDataToAllPlayers:data withDataMode:GKMatchSendDataReliable error:&error];
NSLog(@"Sent data to all players %s ", success ? "Successfully" : "has failed");

gamekitHelper = nil;

if (!success) {

    NSLog(@"Error sending data:%@", error.localizedDescription);

    [[GCTurnBasedMatchHelper sharedGameKitHelper] appAlert:@"Error Sending Data" alertMessage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", error.localizedDescription] viewController:[DominoTableViewController dominotableViewController] gkMatchDisconnect:true];
}
}
```

I have the following code to receive a random number from all other players in the GKMatch:

```
-(void)match:(GKMatch *)match didReceiveData:(NSData *)data fromPlayer:(NSString *)playerID {
Message * message = (Message *)[data bytes];

    if (message->messageType == kMessageTypeRandomNumber) {

        MessageRandomNumber * messageRandomNumber = (MessageRandomNumber *) [data bytes];
        NSLog(@"Received random number: %d", messageRandomNumber- >randomNumber);
```

My problem is that on my iPhone 5 (No sim card, iOS 9.3.1) and iPod Touch (5th gen), messageRandomNumber->randomNumber is always equal to 0 when it receives the random number from the other 3 players connected in the match.  This same exact code works perfectly fine on iphone 5s (No sim card, iOS 9.3.1).  Is there an explanation for this behavior?

Comment: What is `MessageRandomNumber`? Not alloc/init? Is `data` the same before sending/receiving? I'm wondering if there is not an issue with 32bits vs 64 bits.

Comment: @Larme MessageRandom number is

    typedef struct {
      Message message;
      uint32_t randomNumber;
    } MessageRandomNumber;

Comment: I was able to solve my issue.  The problem was I had kMessageTypeRandomNumber in a typedef NS_ENUM set to NSUInteger.  I changed NSUInteger to int32_t and it now works.  The working code looks like:

    typedef NS_ENUM(int32_t) {
         kMessageTypeRandomNumber = 0;
    };